# printing array from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to print an array from mysql table data to a physical printer, I've tried this method but it prints an empty page

```
$queryString = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE order_id='".$order_id."' and confirm_order='0'";
$fetch = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($queryString));

                $handle = printer_open("POS");
                printer_start_doc($handle, "My Document");
                printer_start_page($handle);
                $font = printer_create_font("Arial", 35, 20, 300, false, false, false, 0);
                printer_select_font($handle, $font);

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch)) {
                    printer_draw_text($handle, $row[item_quantity], 10, 10);                
                }

                printer_delete_font($font);
                printer_end_page($handle);
                printer_end_doc($handle);
                printer_close($handle);
```

Comment: don't use mysql_*.. you should use PDO or mysqli_**

Comment: Just by the way... Your code is vulnerable for SQL Injection. I suggest you to use prepared statements

Comment: @BilalAhmed still not working, it's not about mysql or mysqli I guess

Comment: @Clijsters I know I'm just testing something on my local wamp server, but thanks